# Sammy JS forcing a notFound

Tags: javascript, sammy.js

I'm currently trying to force a notFound response when certain parameters are met in sammy js:

```
this.get('#/projects/:url', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'package.php',
                data: {
                    'url-verify': this.params['url']
                },
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.success)
                    {
                        this.load('page.php?='+this.params['url'])
                        .swap();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //force 404
                    }
                }
            });

        });
```

I already have the code set up if a notFound were to be present, but the issue is how do I force a "notFound" if, in my case above, the feedback for the AJAX comes back with an error?

Comment: Do you mean HTTP 404 notFound status code? If so, it's not possible just using JS in browser. As when you receive the response the request itself has already finished, and you can not change the response status any more.

Comment: But you can invoke the notFound handler manually in your AJAX code if you can access it from where your AJAX code is.

Comment: How do you invoke it manually?

Comment: if you can access it from your code, e.g.: you have it reference in the global scope.